# using mediaReorder in service. audio works - crashes on video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service, android-mediarecorder

```
if (audio == true & video == true) 
{
Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoSize(640,480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder((MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT));
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(null);
filesuffix = ".mp4";
filename = formatteddate.concat(filesuffix);
recorder.setOutputFile(path.concat(filename));
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
try {recorder.prepare();} 
catch (IllegalStateException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
recorder.start();
};
```

### it creates the file, then the service crashes.

logcat reports fail on:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at [         ].PPS.onCreate(PPS.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3033)
```

### when recording only audio, works excellent. any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What line is the exception on? start()? prepare()? Something else?